# Spring formBackingObject with polymorphism

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am having a problem to design a wizard module in current Spring application. Use pick up a type of report then fill in necessary data to create the report

The whole wizard process consists merely 2 steps:

```
Step1: a view with a single drop-down menu, allow user to choose
       report type, click next

Step2: based on the report user has chosen, the second view should 
       show up whatever fields required for user to fill in. Once 
       user check finish, The application generates the report.
```

Apparently the second step include polymorphism. The ideal option would be

```
public class Report{
    private String type; // for the first step of wizard
    private IReport report; // for the second step of wizard
    ........
}
```

Interface IReport can be just an empty interface. Then each specific report may have specific fields

```
public class MicroReport implements IReport{
    private String microUnit;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date dueDate;
    .....
}

public class MacroReport implements IReport{
    private List<String> macroUnit;
    private int level;
    private Date generatedDate;
    .....
}
```

I would expect in each JSTL, the html object can be named like:

```
microReport.jspx:
<input name="microreport.report.microUnit" value="..."></input>


macroReport.jspx:
<input name="macroreport.report.macroUnit[0]" value="..."></input>
<input name="macroreport.report.macroUnit[1]" value="..."></input>
<input name="macroreport.report.macroUnit[2]" value="..."></input>
.....
```

However in this case, how to define Spring formBackingObject? Any advice is appreciated.